ANDing conditions for XML data using LINQ
I have XML data that looks like this (simplified)
<customer>
   <id>01</id>
   <name>John</name>
   <discount id='plumb' />
   <discount id='lumber' />
</customer>
<customer>
   <id>02</id>
   <name>Susan</name>
   <discount id='fasten' />
   <discount id='lumber' />
</customer>
<customer>
   <id>03</id>
   <name>Paul</name>
   <discount id='garden' />
   <discount id='plumb' />
</customer>

I need to get the name of the customer that has both a plumbing discount and a lumber discount, which is John, #1. There are many customers with many different discounts.
I can OR the query using LINQ
var xml = XElement.Load(@"C:\customers.xml");
var result = from customer in xml.Descendants("customer")
from discount in customer.Descendants("discount")
where (string)discount.Attribute("id").Value == "plumb" || (string)discount.Attribute("id").Value == "lumber"
select customer.Descendants("name");

which returns John, Susan, and Paul, but ANDing returns none since no single discount id can equal both "plumb" and "lumber".
I'm generally unfamiliar with LINQ. I used it in a project a decade ago. I could use a more verbose method, iterating the discount nodes of each customer, but I'd rather look for help.

Using from discount in customer.Descendants("discount") makes things complicated because at that point you're dealing with individual discounts, whereas your logic needs to examine multiple discounts per customer.
Instead, here's one way you could write the query:
// Version 1
var result =
    from customer in xml.Descendants("customer")
    where customer.Descendants("discount").Any(discount => discount.Attribute("id").Value == "plumb")
       && customer.Descendants("discount").Any(discount => discount.Attribute("id").Value == "lumber")
    select customer.Descendants("name");

This version puts the two discount checks into a single where clause, combined with &&.
You can eliminate some of the repetitive code by counting the number of matching discounts and verifying that the number equals two:
// Version 2 (assumes that no <customer> has duplicate <discount> elements)
var result =
    from customer in xml.Descendants("customer")
    where (from discount in customer.Descendants("discount")
           where discount.Attribute("id").Value == "plumb"
              || discount.Attribute("id").Value == "lumber"
           select discount).Count() == 2
    select customer.Descendants("name");

But you might find this version to be less readable than the first.

Both of these versions select every customer that has the "plumb" discount, the "lumber" discount, and possibly other discounts too:
<!-- This customer will also be selected -->
<customer>
   <id>04</id>
   <name>Mary</name>
   <discount id='garden' />
   <discount id='plumb' />
   <discount id='lumber' />
</customer>

By contrast, the answer posted by Yong Shun (as of this writing) does something different: It selects every customer that doesn't have a discount other than "plumb" and "lumber". The difference? It will select customers that have only the "plumb" discount, customers that have only the "lumber" discount, and customers that have no discounts at all. Also, it won't select customers that have the "plumb" and "lumber" discounts but other discounts too, like Mary above.
